# Specify C and C++ compiler paths when building Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, build, mkmf, ruby-native-extensions

`gem` allows specifying build arguments, however I can't find a build argument to override the `CC` and `CXX` constants in the Makefile generated by `mkmf` (the defaults appear to come from `RbConfig::CONFIG`).

How can I specify which compiler to use when building an extension?